# Map object and nested object to model using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord

I have an object like

```
{"Result":[{
    "Links":[{
            "UrlTo":"http://www.example.com/",
            "Visited":1364927598,
            "FirstSeen":1352031217,
            "PrevVisited":1362627231,
            "Anchor":"example.com",
            "Type":"Text",
            "Flag":[],
            "TextPre":"",
            "TextPost":""
        }],
    "Index":0,
    "Rating":0.001416,
    "UrlFrom":"http://www.exampletwo.com",
    "IpFrom":"112.213.89.105",
    "Title":"Example title",
    "LinksInternal":91,
    "LinksExternal":51,
    "Size":5735
}]}
```

And I have a model with all of the keys.

UrlTo, Visited, FirstSeen, PrevVisited, Anchor, Type, TextPre, TextPost, Index, Rating, UrlFrom, IpFrom, Title, LinksInternal, LinksExternal, Size

I understand how to save this to the database without this bit below...

```
"Links":[{
            "UrlTo":"http://example.com/",
            "Visited":1364927598,
            "FirstSeen":1352031217,
            "PrevVisited":1362627231,
            "Anchor":"example.com",
            "Type":"Text",
            "Flag":[],
            "TextPre":"",
            "TextPost":""
        }],
```

Not sure how to save it with a nested object as well.

I had a search on Google and SO and couldn't find anything, what is the correct way to do this? Should I move the nested object into the one above? I have no need for it to be nested...

Thanks in advance

Comment: based on the json above, you could be sent multiple links (it is an array). in that case, what would you like to do?

Comment: The API the json is coming from for some reason never gives multiple links, just multiple results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you want to save links, so I would loop over the Result/Links in the json provided, and create a new hash based on the links.

I've pretended below that your json is in a file called input.json -- but you'd obviously just parse the text or use an existing JSON object

```
require 'json'
json = JSON.parse File.read("input.json")

links = json["Result"].map do |result|
  result["Links"].map {|link| link }
end.flatten

hash = {"Links" => links}
puts hash
```

This creates the object:

```
{"Links"=>[{"UrlTo"=>"http://www.example.com/", "Visited"=>1364927598, "FirstSeen"=>1352031217, "PrevVisited"=>1362627231, "Anchor"=>"example.com", "Type"=>"Text", "Flag"=>[], "TextPre"=>"", "TextPost"=>""}]}
```

Comment: I want all of the data so maybe it would be better to have it like


{"Result":[{
    "UrlTo":"http://www.example.com/",
    "Visited":1364927598,
    "FirstSeen":1352031217,
    "PrevVisited":1362627231,
    "Anchor":"example.com",
    "Type":"Text",
    "Flag":[],
    "TextPre":"",
    "TextPost":"",
    "Index":0,
    "Rating":0.001416,
    "UrlFrom":"http://www.exampletwo.com",
    "IpFrom":"112.213.89.105",
    "Title":"Example title",
    "LinksInternal":91,
    "LinksExternal":51,
    "Size":5735
}]}

and just move the array into the one above?

Comment: You need to either flatten this into a simple hash, or have two objects (result with a link child), or store the JSON rather than columns. It all depends on how you want to store the data. You should start there.

Comment: @MaxRose-Collins Sure -- if you felt I helped you, please mark this as the correct answer.